# Error HTTP 404.11 passing account activation Token by querystring

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-5, identity, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement password reset funcionallity. I use the ASP.NET Identity.

I am using the `UserManager.GetConfirmationToken` that returns a token like this:

> UW/cj4xUj08kiGCntnWs7z1eUcWlyfNczH5IZfvf0ScTi4L1jgdkkus/Zb5ROJOWb%2b1XAVRSiBUvVGnESfEyauDDa4u%2bPDUH6D/CIpwPcFYRvLi%2b%2bq6f%2bRIhKHRTsGMV0y8lXpSZ5VqySWGSSaW9kofGage/IjW4HrvONeEtA4Szov3u7HgmqEUf0yzgivJ0

Then, I compose my URL and I send it by Email to the registered user. The url to activate the account is like this:

```
http://localhost:4322/Account/Confirm/UW/cj4xUj08kiGCntnWs7z1eUcWlyfNczH5IZfvf0ScTi4L1jgdkkus/Zb5ROJOWb%2b1XAVRSiBUvVGnESfEyauDDa4u%2bPDUH6D/CIpwPcFYRvLi%2b%2bq6f%2bRIhKHRTsGMV0y8lXpSZ5VqySWGSSaW9kofGage/IjW4HrvONeEtA4Szov3u7HgmqEUf0yzgivJ0
```

When I click, this error occurs:
`Error HTTP 404.11 - Double escape sequence issue`

Comment: Did find a way to solve this? The answer you accepted doesn't work.

Comment: I found the answer 7 minutes later after i wrote previous comment. Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to encode URL using [httputility.urlencode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Did this answer actually help you? In my case it seems MVC is parsing the %2b to a + sign and then fails. ex: hxxp://adomain/test/ex%2bample is encoded with HttpUtility.UrlEncode or Uri.EscapeDataString (which differs by writing %2B instead. None seems to work with MVC5.1, IIS8.5

Comment: This is not working. Could you please improve your answer with some examples?

Answer (score 3):

The underlying problem here is trying to add confirmation code to the path. Whereas it should be sent via querystring.
So it should be like this

```
http://localhost:4322/Account/Confirm?code=UW/cj4xUj08kiGCntnWs7z1eUcWlyfNczH5IZfvf0ScTi4L1jgdkkus/Zb5ROJOWb%2b1XAVRSiBUvVGnESfEyauDDa4u%2bPDUH6D/CIpwPcFYRvLi%2b%2bq6f%2bRIhKHRTsGMV0y8lXpSZ5VqySWGSSaW9kofGage/IjW4HrvONeEtA4Szov3u7HgmqEUf0yzgivJ0
```

This will save day whose tries to solve this problem.

I found the answer at this comment : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx?PageIndex=1#comments Thanks to pranav rostgi

Comment: Actually, for me, the value after `code=` had to be urlencoded too. But thanks, your answer helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Your token contains `/` symbols wich are being parsed as a path to some server page. You can either encode it somehow (maybe base64) and use as query string parameter like `...?token=...`. Or change token generations so it will contain only *good* symbols

Comment: Ok, but do you know how to change the token generations on Asp.NET MVC5 membership? 

I have search but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't double encoding the token, so you can do something like this to send the email:

```
                string code = await UserManager.GetConfirmationToken(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Both the token and the resulting URL still contains the "/" character.

Is there any way to change the token generator in ASP.NET MVC5 membership?

Comment: This didn't work for me either - the token includes characters which would need to be encoded to be passed in a URL.